# Wrapping 2 HOC to a component in React

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Is there a way I can wrap two HOCs together?

```
export default withRouter(Page)
export default withTranslation()(Page);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this? It should probably work.

```js
export default withRouter(withTranslation()(Page));
```